# PowerShell Array from Excel

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import data from excel into powershell

2 columns one is the group and the other is the users - example below

```
Groups  Users
domain group1   ssmith, bjones,pduke
domain group2   mleed,jpark
```

I need the users column to be an array so when I put it into a for each loop it will add all the users into the group. I found how to do it of they are in a  1 to 1 relationship but not 1 to many - this does not work with multiple users in the user column

```
import-csv "C:\qt\users_add.csv" | Group-Object Group | % {
    # Foreach Group, get ADUser object for users and add members
    $users = $_.Group | % { Get-ADUser $_.users }
    Add-ADGroupMember  $_.Name -Member $users
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-split` based on the delimiter, example below.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\qt\users_add.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Groups -Members ($_.Users -split ',')
}
```

Comment: That worked I had to modify it to loop with a Foreach$import=import-Csv -Path 'C:\qt\users_add.csv'  
Foreach($o in $import)
{
    Add-ADGroupMember $o.Group -Members ($o.Users -split ',')